# Accurate "Sieve of Erathostenes" to determine primality of BigInteger in C#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, primes, biginteger

The problem I am trying to solve is to find the primality of an arbitrarily long number ([BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)) in C#. To achieve this task, I have implemented the "[Sieve of Erathostenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)". The algorithm is already fast, but in terms of accuracy, I am skeptical as I am unsure of how accurate BigInteger is in representing arbitrarily long numbers.

**The "Sieve of Erathostenes" algorithm**

```
public static bool IsPrime(BigInteger value)
{
    int result = 0;
    // 2, 3, 5 and 7 are the base primes used in the Sieve of Erathostenes
    foreach (int prime in new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 })
    {
        // If the value is the base prime, it's prime - no further calculation required.
        if (value == prime)
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Else, we need to work out if the value is divisible, by any of these primes...
        BigInteger remainder = 0;
        BigInteger.DivRem(value, prime, out remainder);

        if (remainder != 0)
        {
            // We increment result to indicate that the value was not divisible by the base prime
            result++;
        }
    }

    // If result is 4, thus, not divisible my any of the base primes, it must be prime.
    return result == 4;
}
```

My question is not "why is my code not working" - it's more "is this accurately determining primality of BigInteger"

Specifically, I would like to know about the accuracy of [BigInteger.DivRem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.divrem.aspx)

Comment: This is *not* the Sieve of Eratosthenes, and is not a correct algorithm to determine primes. DivRem itself is not a problem an won't "lose" precision - it's all integer math anyway.

Comment: @user2864740, can you explain why this is not the Sieve of Eratosthenes? - According to the illustration on the wiki article, if the number is divisible by 2, 3, 5 or 7 it is not prime - My algorithm checks exactly this, doesn't it?

Comment: ... By that logic, 121 is prime.

Comment: @Rawling, well spotted! Is appears that my algorithm does not filter prime squares at all...back to the drawing board

Comment: @series0ne - the problem is not that 121 is a square (11*11). 11*13 would also be seen as "prime" by your code, because it contains only factors > 7.

Comment: @series0ne - that wikipedia example stops at 7 because that is the largest prime less than the square root of 120. Once you get past that root, you have scratched out all higher non-primes because they also contain lower factors.

Comment: Please use Miller-Rabin for this. The sieve is only useful for generating **ranges** of prime numbers; otherwise you are generating a lot of prime numbers you don't really need, and incur in a cost of operations that is _exponential_ in the length of the number (which for a BigInt can be hundreds of digits), whereas Miller-Rabin is polynomic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sieve of Erathostenes is work as follow:

- First assume that all numbers is prime.
- Starting from 2, crossing out all the numbers that is a multiple of two. Then, move to the next number that is not crossed out, and remove all multiple of this number, and so on... so, in the end what is left is the list of prime number.

So clearly, your code is not Sieve of Erathostenes, which you **made an assumption** that the list of prime is only 2,3,5,7

To check whether a number is a prime or not, we can have a more easy way, instead of using Sieve of Erathostenes, which is only suitable when you want to generate a list of prime numbers.

Pseudo Code:

```
boolean isPrime(int num){

    for(int i = 2; i*i <= num ; i++){
        if(num % i == 0){
           return false;
        }            
    }
    return true;
}
```